# Generated function code with declarations on multiple lines

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Android studio splits the function signature and it's declarations across multiple lines, how to turn off this setting?

This also happens when I apply Code -> Reformat Code

```
val handler = object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
    override fun onMove(
        recyclerView: RecyclerView,
        viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
        target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    ): Boolean {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Kotlin` and change `Function declaration parameters` value to `Do not wrap`.[image]